# Show a modal on beforeunload for some time, then leave page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show a modal with a message when a user leaves the page, I'm doing it on ajax call success, my problem is that if this happens too quickly the user won't have time to read the message before the browser goes to another page, this is how I'm doing it:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(event){
        // Setting some vars
        $.ajax({
            // Some ajax attrs
            beforeSend: function(){$("#partial_review_modal").modal('show')},
            success: function(){$("#partial_review_modal").delay(600).modal('hide')},
        }
    });
});
```

Obviously if the ajax call returns too quickly the message won't show up for long enough, and .delay() won't make it show for the specified time since the browser is already leaving to another page.

Any hints on how can I make it so that the browser waits for a while before leaving?

**Edit:** the whole purpose of showing this modal is informing the user that the data that has been filled in a form is being saved so that he can come back later and finish filling it, this involves saving some stuff to my DB (I use Django with Postgres). Also I wanted to make it so that the user could not leave this page before the ajax call returned, I thought this was enough for the object being saved to my DB but apparently it isn't since when I load the page again some of the things that should be removed by the ajax call are not yet removed, but if I refresh the page these effectively dissappear, adding to why I wanted to wait a little bit before leaving the page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delay leaving a page via javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495553/how-can-i-delay-leaving-a-page-via-javascript)

Comment: Thanks @JosephCho! It is indeed the same question, thou they only recommend not to do it at all, but I believe it wouldn't be bad in my case so if someone knows how to do this please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a good idea, but lets give a try...
What about to make sure that the user will read the message?
Give him whatever the time he needs...
All we got do is add a return in the end of the method for a default browser confirmation, just like that:

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload",function() {
    $.ajax({
        // Some ajax attrs
        beforeSend: function(){$("#partial_review_modal").modal('show')},
        success: function(){$("#partial_review_modal").delay(600).modal('hide')}, 3000)},
        });

        return 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?'
});
```

Comment: This would be a good way of making sure the user actually has time to read the message, but it would also defeat the purpose of the message modal, which is to show the user some information about what is happening in the background (ajax call) so that he knows that action is taking place (i save a partial state of a form to my DB). I will edit my OP with aditional information about the ajax call